# How do I add an object to the end of the array?

Tags: reactjs

How do I add an object to the end of the array?

I am trying to do this, but I end up with an object with one element:

```
  const [wokSummary, setWokSummary] = useState({
    wok: null
  });

  const onAdded = item => {
    const arr = [{ ...wokSummary.wok, item }];
    setWokSummary({
      wok: arr
    });
  };
```

Comment: sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-cherry-pi8xn?file=/src/App.js:97-289

Comment: wokSummary is not an array. I guess the array you are referring to is wokSummary, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating one single object, simply remove the object assignment e.g.

```
const [wokSummary, setWokSummary] = useState({
    wok: []
  });

const arr = [ ...wokSummary.wok, item ];
```

And you have do initialize `wok` with an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `{}` brackets that are inside the list  brackets `[]`:

```
  const [wokSummary, setWokSummary] = useState({
    wok: null
  });

  const onAdded = item => {
    const arr = [...wokSummary.wok, item];
    setWokSummary({
      wok: arr
    });
  };
```

Your item is the new object, and it is being appended as an element of the list.
`...wokSummary.wok` spreads `wokSummary.wok` elements, each element contains an object.